# How to dynamically dispatch based on enrichment?

Tags: json, scala, spray, enrich-my-library

The [spray-json](http://github.com/spray/spray-json) library extends basic Scala types with a `toJson` method. I'd like to convert an `Any` into a [`JsValue`](http://spray.github.com/spray/api/spray-json/#cc.spray.json.JsValue) if there is such a pimp for the underlying type. My best attempt works, but is verbose:

```
import cc.spray._

val maybeJson1: PartialFunction[Any, JsValue] = {
  case x: BigDecimal => x.toJson
  case x: BigInt => x.toJson
  case x: Boolean => x.toJson
  case x: Byte => x.toJson
  case x: Char => x.toJson
  case x: Double => x.toJson
  case x: Float => x.toJson
  case x: Int => x.toJson
  case x: Long => x.toJson
  case x: Short => x.toJson
  case x: String => x.toJson
  case x: Symbol => x.toJson
  case x: Unit => x.toJson
}
```

Ideally, I'd prefer something (impossible) like this:

```
def maybeJson2(any: Any): Option[JsValue] = {
  if (pimpExistsFor(any))
    Some(any.toJson)
  else
    None  
}
```

Is there a way to do this without enumerating every type that has been enriched?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way, but it requires a *lot* of reflection and therefore is quite a headache.  The basic idea is as follows.  The `DefaultJsonProtocol` object inherits a bunch of traits that contain implicit objects which contain `write` methods.  Each of those will have an accessor function, but you won't know what it's called.  Basically, you'll just take *all* methods that take no parameters and return one object that has a `write` method that takes the class of your object and returns a `JsValue`.  If you find exactly one such method that returns one such class, use reflection to call it.  Otherwise, bail.

It would look *something* like this (warning, untested):

```
def canWriteMe(writer: java.lang.Class[_], me: java.lang.Class[_]): 
  Option[java.lang.reflect.Method] =
{
  writer.getMethods.find(_.getName == "write").filter{ m =>
    classOf[JsValue].isAssignableFrom(m.getReturnType) && {
      val parm = m.getParameterTypes()
      m.length == 1 && parm(0).isAssignableFrom(me)
    }
  }
}
def maybeJson2(any: Any): Option[JsValue] = {
  val couldWork = {
    DefaultJsonProtocol.getClass.getMethods.
      filter(_.getParameterTypes.length==0).
      flatMap(m => canWriteMe(m.getReturnType, any.getClass).map(_ -> m))
  }
  if (couldWork.length != 1) None else {
    couldWork.headOption.map{ case (wrMeth, obMeth) =>
      val wrObj = obMeth.invoke(DefaultJsonProtocol)
      val answer = wrMeth.invoke(wrObj, any)
    }
  }
}
```

Anyway, you're best off pulling the `DefaultJsonProtocol` class apart in the REPL step by step and finding out how to reliably identify the objects that define the writers, and then get the `write` methods out of them.

Comment: Yes, it looks like quite a headache! :) I think I'll stick with my current setup. Perhaps this is a job for (the future implementation of) macros?

Comment: @MidoriKid - Macros are unlikely to help that much--the core of your problem is run-time type identification.  Dynamics or type tags might help a little, but I think the problem is _actually this hard_.  This is essentially what you are doing when you solve the problem by hand using javadocs.  If you really are using a wide diversity of types, something like this is, despite the nontrivial amount of work, the way to do it.  Anything else invites error as you repeat yourself many times, and invites getting out of date whenever anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it will fit you needs, but here is an alternative approach wich is really simple and type-safe.

If you kept the type of the argument (instead of using `Any`) you could rely on implicit parameter resolution to find the correct conversion at compile time:

```
def toJson[T:JsonFormat]( t: T ): JsValue = implicitly[JsonFormat[T]].write(t)
```

You won't need an option, because the program will fail at compile time if you try to pass an argument which is not "pimpable".

Comment: I expect this will be very useful in the future (+1), but it doesn't fit my current need, which has a signature something like: `Seq[Any] => Seq[Option[JsValue]]`

Comment: This is statically dispatched -- i.e. it only works "if you kept the type of the argument", as you say. The question specifically asks for a dynamically dispatched approach, where the type is not known at compile time.